# How to make this button position relative?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a checkbox which I have converted into a ON-OFF button. But it only works when the label has `position: absolute`. How can I achieve the same using `position: relative` so it doesn't hamper the display of the entire page ?

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position:absolute;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    line-height: 30px; 
    height: 27px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
    content: ""; 
    width: 94px; 
    height: 27px;
    background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/391082/sprite2.png) -56px 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background-position: -3px 0;
}
```

```html
<input id=test type=checkbox value=test checked>
<label for=test></label>
```

Comment: Wrap both elements in a new `position: relative`-styled element (could be a `<div>`), and define a width/height on the new parent element.

Comment: The label itself is not `position:absolute`, the pseudo is, though that does not dictate how it position itself

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 2):

If you give the `label` `display: inline-block` and a height/width, and you use the general sibling selector `~` instead, you will have a good solution

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position:absolute;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
}
input[type="checkbox"] ~ label[for=test] {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 27px;
  width: 94px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
input[type="checkbox"] ~ label[for=test]::before {
  content: "";
  width: 94px;
  height: 27px;
  background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/391082/sprite2.png) -56px 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label[for=test]::before {
  background-position: -3px 0;
}
```

```html
<input id=test type=checkbox value=test checked>

You<br> can 
<label for=test></label>
do like this
```

If you control the markup fully, the adjacent sibling selector `+` might be even better

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position:absolute;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 27px;
  width: 94px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
  content: "";
  width: 94px;
  height: 27px;
  background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/391082/sprite2.png) -56px 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  background-position: -3px 0;
}
```

```html
You<br> can 
<input id=test type=checkbox value=test checked>
<label for=test></label>
do like this
```

Comment: do not use the general sibling selector for this. The adjacent sibling is better suited if you control the html. Otherwise it might affect other labels which are not related to the checkbox. I understand that you example code needs this, but there is no reason to put text between the two elements since the checkbox is hidden anyway, But you get my vote for the solution to the actual problem :) .

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thanks :) ... and I solved that "target other labels" issue by using the `for` attribute, and as it uses an id that won't happen, still, added a 2:nd sample using the adjacent sibling.